# Как узнать результат выбранный в MessageBox?

Tags: windows, winforms, c++-cli

Когда запустить данный код выскочит окно с кнопками Да или Нет.

```
MessageBox::Show("Error","Error",
MessageBoxButtons::YesNo,
MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
```

Задача состоит в том как узнать какую кнопку нажал пользователь

Comment: Укажите из какой библиотеки этот MessageBox. Стандарт С++ не предусматривает такого метода.

Comment: @Arkady Никакой! Этот метод для WindowsForm

Comment: Что такое WindowsForm?

Comment: @Arkady https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms

Comment: отлично, теперь, прочитав первое предложение в этой статье, Вы сможете указать в вопросе, из какой библиотеки эта функция?

Answer (score 3):

Это C++/CLI, а не чистый C++.

Метод `MessageBox::Show` возвращает [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) - в вашем случае это или `DialogResult::Yes`, или `DialogResult::No`:

```
if (MessageBox::Show("Error","Error",
                      MessageBoxButtons::YesNo,
                      MessageBoxIcon::Warning) == ::DialogResult::Yes)
{
    // что-то сделать
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если это `MessageBox` на *Windows*, то возвращает `IDYES` или `IDNO` (6 или 7).

Comment: А не подскажите как написать условие IF?

Comment: if(MessageBox::Show("Error","Error",
MessageBoxButtons::YesNo,
MessageBoxIcon::Warning) == IDYES) { действо на YES} else {действо на NO}

Comment: Спасибо. Нужно подключать какую нибудь библиотеку? У меня пишет что IDYES неопределенный идентификатор

Comment: это не библиотека, а в хедере. MSDN пишет Header


Winuser.h (include Windows.h). Ну или вчистую, как  писал вместо определения препроцессора 5 и 6 цифры

Comment: черт, перепутал, 6 и 7 цифры

Comment: @maint Не надо учить плохому. :)